# not able to install the apache2 in NAME="openSUSE Leap" VERSION="15.4"

Tags: apache2, opensuse

When I am trying to install the apache2 in Open Suse leap 15.4 it throwing the below issue.

> Problem: nothing provides 'libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.34)(64bit)' needed by the to be installed apache2-2.4.57-289.4.x86_64

> Solution 1: do not install apache2-2.4.57-289.4.x86_64

> Solution 2: break apache2-2.4.57-289.4.x86_64 by ignoring some of its dependencies`

Is there any solution available to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

SUSE Linux, including Leap, already contains a tested copy of Apache2.

In case you must use the latest development build of apache2, make sure to use the `Leap` rather than the `Factory/Tumbleweed` repository.